# Gradle syntax confusion

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

I know this is a dependencies task and it is a method which takes closure. I have concepts of closures but still I can understand what are these `compile value`. If I click on compile in gradle `build.script` it takes me to this     `Dependency add(String configurationName, Object dependencyNotation);` function. Can you please explain this syntax ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an **external dependency**.

This is a dependency on some files built outside the current build, and stored in a repository of some kind, such as Maven central, or a corporate Maven or Ivy repository, or a directory in the local file system.

There are different notations supported for declaring a dependency on an external module:

```
 compile group: 'com.android.support', name: 'recyclerview-v7', version: '23.1.1'
```

or

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
```

The `configurationName` in this case is:

```
configurationName "group:name:version:classifier@extension"
```

or with a map notation:

```
configurationName group: group, name: name, version: version, classifier: classifier, ext: extension
```

More info [here.](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html#N105EC)